# Is there a necessary and sufficient condition for the tangent bundle of a fiber bundle to be trivial?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

My question is very basic (I don't know too much of differential geometry):
given a fiber bundle, is there a necessary and sufficient condition for its tangent bundle to be trivial?

I have some ideas, but submitted to some conditions on the cohomology ring of the bundle.
(I apologize if it is trivial.)

Comment: Fiber bundles don't in general have tangent spaces.  The tangent space at a point $x$ makes sense when you have a ringed space `$(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$` such that the stalk of the structure sheaf at $x$, $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is a local ring.  Then the Zariski cotangent space is defined to be $Cot_x:=\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$, where $\mathfrak{m}$ is the maximal ideal of the stalk. The tangent space is defined to be the dual space $Hom(Cot_x,k)$, where $k$ is the residue field of the stalk at $x$.  

Comment: I think you mean that the tangent *bundle* (not 'space') be trivial.  I've edited accordingly.

Comment: @fpqc: given the 'dg' tag, I think we can safely assume that we are in the category of smooth manifolds.

Comment: @José: What's the difference between a "tangent bundle" and a "tangent space"?

@fpqc: A fiber bundle is, among other things, a smooth manifold, so it indeed has a tangent bundle (or space). In particular, it's certainly a ringed space, so your definitions (which are rarely used in differential geometry) minus the adjective "Zariski" can certainly be used to define the tangent bundle. But there are easier ways.

Comment: @Deane: I thought he meant a topological fiber bundle. Also, the tangent space at x is the fiber of the tangent bundle at x.

Comment: @Deane: The convention that I know is that a "tangent space" is a fibre of the "tangent bundle".  Thus we have the tangent space at a point, and all the tangent spaces fit together to form the tangent bundle.

Comment: fpqc and Andrew: Thanks for the clarifications. I guess I do use "tangent space" informally for the bundle and "tangent space at x" for a particular fiber. And the question probably should include an explicit statement that the fiber bundle and its base are assumed to be smooth manifolds.

Comment: krolik- This kind of question is very difficult to answer with no context.  What sort of situation are you working in?  What sort of things do you know that you are hoping imply this?

Comment: @Deane: I follow the convention in Andrew's comment.  I was not aware of the convention by which "tangent space" means "tangent bundle", hence perhaps my edit was unwarranted.  It did confuse me initially.  As for the differentiability assumption, I took that as implicit in the choice of tag.  But I agree it would not be redundant to state it explicitly.

Comment: I guess the question is: "When is the total space of a smooth fiber bundle a parallelizable manifold?"

Comment: Just to make things simple, perhaps we could consider the case of principal bundles first, cause Lie groups are parallelizable manifolds...

Comment: What ideas do you have? I guess one could use Serre's spectral sequence combined with some characteristic classes argument, but I don't know too much about the subject.

Comment: @José: I now think your edit was appropriate. And like you I assumed smoothness implicitly. And I agree that it does seem better to say things explicitly. @unknown: Thanks for pointing out that Lie groups are a good motivating example.

Comment: The question is still somewhat ambiguous.  Do you want to bundle of tangent spaces to the fibres of your fibre bundle, or the tangent bundle to the total space of your fibre bundle?  I suspect you want the latter. 

Comment: @Deane: You are technically more correct we are!  The tangent bundle is the morphism  $p:TM\to M$, while the total space of the tangent bundle (the tangent space) is $TM$.  Calling $TM$ the tangent bundle is an abuse of notation!

Comment: yes i asked myself when the total space of a fiber bundle is parallelizable manifold, ie if it is readable on the filber bundle intrinsequely ( one algebraic property, if it makes sense in this context)

Comment: Silly example: G Lie group, H closed subgroup, $G\rightarrow G/H$ is a (principal) fiber bundle whose total space (=G) is parallelizable. Can this picture be generalized a bit?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is far from being a complete answer, but there is a case when one construct a parallelizable bundle (meaning its total space has trivial tangent bundle) from a given (geometric) bundle.

The context is that of $G$-structure, which are a formalization of the concept of geometric structures. A $G$-structure is a set of data including a fiber bundle on a smooth manifold, which shall be thought of as the bundle of admissible frames. For example, in the Riemannian case ($G=O(n)$) the bundle is that of orthonormal frames. If the group $G$ has a finite-order rigidity property, then one can construct a sequence of bundles, the total space of each one being the base space of the next one, so that after a finite number of steps one gets a bundle whose total space is parallelizable. This is a tool to prove that the group of automorphisms of the $G$-structure is a Lie group. As an example, if I remember well the total space of the bundle of orthonormal frames on a Riemannian manifold is parallelizable.

All details are available in Kobayashi's *transformation groups in differential geometry*.

Comment: I really like this answer; it gives a nice generalization to the fact that the tangent bundle of a Lie group is trivial. Indeed, the tangent bundle of the principal $O(n)$-bundle of orthonormal frames of a Riemannian manifold is parallelizable. This is a standard fact in exterior differential systems, explained often by Robert Bryant. It seems to me that the same argument shows that *any* principal $G$-bundle constructed from tangent frames (not necessarily orthonormal) has a parallelizable tangent bundle. You just need to construct a connection on that bundle to get the trivialization.

Answer (score 13):

As the comments indicate, the level of generality of the question is optimistic. Here's a special case: the product $M\times N$ of smooth manifolds.

Recall that a manifold $X$ is stably parallelizable if $TX\oplus \mathbb{R}$ is trivial. By a standard argument in obstruction theory, this is so as soon as $TX\oplus \mathbb{R}^n$ is trivial for some $n\geq 1$.

I assume $M$ and $N$ connected, positive-dimensional but not necessarily compact. The product $M\times N$ is parallelizable iff $M$ and $N$ are stably parallelizable and one of them has vanishing Euler characteristic.

Euler characteristics $\chi$ are relevant because $\chi(M\times N)=\chi(M)\chi(N)$ and because $\chi$ is precisely the obstruction to having one nowhere-zero vector field.

The "if" direction has a short, elementary proof that I'll leave to you, but you can also look it up in the extremely short paper of E. B. Staples, Proc. A.M.S. 18 no. 3 (1967).
Conversely, if $M\times N$ is parallelizable then, choosing a trivialisation of $T(M\times N)$, and a point $y\in N$, we get by restriction to $M\times y$ a trivialization of $TM\oplus T_y N$. Hence $M$ (and similarly $N$) is stably parallelizable.

Part of this goes over to smooth fibre bundles $E \to B$ with connected base $B$ and fibre $F$: if $TE$ is trivial then $0=\chi(E)=\chi(B)\chi(F)$, and $F$ is stably parallelizable. But the pullback of the Hopf fibration $S^5\to \mathbb{CP}^2$ to $\mathbb{CP}^2\times S^1$ is an example where the total space $S^1\times S^5$ is parallelizable but the base is not stably parallelizable (it has non-vanishing $p_1$).

Answer (score 12):

I just wanted to elaborate on Benoît Kloeckner's answer, so if you like what I say, please upvote his answer.

By a frame, I mean a basis of the tangent space at a point on a smooth
manifold $M$. The space $F$ of all possible frames, called the frame
bundle, is a principal $GL(n)$-bundle over the manifold, $n$ is the
dimension of the manifold. A point in $F$ is given by $(x, e)$, where
$x \in M$, $e = (e_1, \dots, e_n)$, and $e_i \in T_xM$. Associated
with each point is the dual frame $\omega^1, \dots, \omega^n \in
T_x^*M$. Let $\pi: F \rightarrow M$, $\pi(x,e) = x$, denote the
natural projection.

There is a natural set of $n$ $1$-forms $\hat\omega^1, \dots,
\hat\omega^n$ on $F$, which are called either "tautological" or
"semi-basic" and act as follows: If $v \in T_{(x,e)}F$, then
$
\langle \hat\omega^i,v\rangle = \langle\omega^i,\pi_* v \rangle,
$
where $\omega^1, \dots, \omega^n \in T^*_xM$ form a dual basis to the basis
$e_1, \dots, e_n \in T_xM$. These forms have the universal property
that given any section $s: M \rightarrow F$, $s^*\bar\omega^i$ are
$1$-forms on $M$ dual to the moving frame given by the $e_i$.

You can check that any connection $\nabla$ on $T_*M$ determines a set
of global $1$-forms $\hat\omega^i_j$ on $F$, such given any section
$s = (s_1, \dots, s_n): M \rightarrow F$, $\nabla s_j =
s_is^*\hat\omega^i_j$. Therefore, a connection on $F$ gives a set of global
$1$-forms $\hat\omega^1, \dots, \hat\omega^n, \hat\omega^1_1, \dots, \hat\omega^n_n$
that trivialize $T^*F$. The dual vector fields
trivialize $T_*F$.

Since there always exists a connection on $T_*M $, this shows that $F$
has a parallelizable tangent bundle. The same argument can be extended
to any principal $G$-bundle of tangent frames. As observed by
Hoeckner, the case $G = O(n)$ corresponds to a Riemannian structure.

This, of course, does not answer the original question, but it is a
important case where the answer is yes. These global $1$-forms are
extremely useful in many contexts; the work of Robert Bryant
illustrates this.

Comment: People also call the collection $\omega^i$ the `soldering
form' You may as well take the $\omega^i _j$ to be
the one-forms encoding the Levi-Civita connection.
It is nice to view the $\omega^i$ pointwise as a linear identification
of the tangent bundle with a `standard' $R^n$.  The $\omega^i_j$
are $so(n)$-valued.  Taken together these forms take values
in the isometry group of $R^n$.  

Answer (score 3):

A huge amount of different geometries (e.g. semi-Riemannian, conformal, projective, CR, etc.) are examples of Cartan geometries. These are curved generalizations of Klein geometries $G \twoheadrightarrow G/P$, where we have a principal $P$-bundle of adapted frames $\mathcal{P} \to M$ and a Cartan connection form $\omega: T\mathcal{P} \to \mathfrak{g}$ generalizing the Maurer-Cartan form.

And just as the Maurer-Cartan form gives a parallelization of the canonical principal $P$-bundle in Klein geometry $TG \cong G \times \mathfrak{g}$, so does the Cartan connection give a parallelization of the adapted frame bundle in Cartan geometry $T\mathcal{P} \cong \mathcal{P} \times \mathfrak{g}$.

So in practice quite a lot of principal bundles of interest will have trivial tangent bundles.